# JAXB/MOXy: Mapping elements with unknown names as specific classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I'm attempting to handle mapping some XML nodes with my existing JAXB/MOXy code and I'm having some trouble determining if what I want to do is even possible.

Essentially, I have some XML data below and although each node has a different name (that I don't know a priori), they have the same structure/content so I'd like to unmarshall them all as instances of the same class; perhaps storing the element name with @XmlPath("@name").

I've looked at using the @XmlAnyElement tag, but I can't work out how to unmarshall as a custom class rather than instances of ElementNSImpl.

Is this even possible with JAXB/MOXy?

```
<node-group>
    <node_a index="1">
        <value>Alpha</value>
    </node_a>
    <node_b index="2">
        <value>Beta</value>
    </node_b>
    <node_c index="3">
        <value>Charlie</value>
    </node_c>
</node-group>
```